# Why a keyboard shortcut does work in a one app and does not in another?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, ventura

I have a single shortcut for Enter/Exit Full Screen.

Works fine for apps, but in the same time it does work for another app.
[Miro (Desktop/M1)](https://miro.com/apps/) in my example.

The shortcut is still presented for the app. Why it does not work?

OS: MacOS Ventura v13.6

[image: Enter/Exit Full Screen shortcut]